# SelectItem disappear when use div in selectOneRadio

Tags: jsf

I'm trying to put a div for each selectItem inside a selectOneRadio, see:]

```
<h:selectOneRadio styleClass="radio"
                    value="#{cursandoMB.alternativasEscolhidas[questaoCurso]}"
                    converter="entityConverter" layout="pageDirection">
                    <c:forEach var="c"
                        items="#{questaoCurso.questao.alternativasPreenchidas}">
                        <h:panelGroup style="color:red;">
                            <f:selectItem itemValue="#{c}" itemLabel="#{c.letra}) #{c.texto}" />
                        </h:panelGroup>
                    </c:forEach>
                </h:selectOneRadio>
```

Nothing is rendered when i do it, but if i comment the lines `<h:panelGroup>` everything works. How can i solve this ?

Comment: I didn't understand why use jsf:id="email" in a component instead of "id=email".

Comment: i read the blog but i didn't understand why use it.

Comment: Explain for me: where is the "hiddenItem" backingBean ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101936/discussion-between-scientist-and-balusc).